# Ruby on Rails error 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a comments section for a simple blog, but when I try to render it I keep getting the error above.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
                Comments
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
                <%= render @comment %>
        </div>
</div>
```

The error is in the <%= render @comment %> line. @comment is nil or undefined.

From my comments controller:

```
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
            format.html {redirect_to blog_post_path(id: @comment.blog_post_id), notice: "Comment was created successfully."}
        else
            format.html {redirect_to blog_post_path(id: @comment.blog_post_id), notice: "Comment failed to post."}
          end
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :comment_entry, :blog_post_id)
  end

  def set_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I can't figure out why it thinks that @comment is set to nil. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What action or route are you using when you see this error?

Comment: I found a simple syntax error in blogs_post_controller.rb, so it wasn't creating a new comment. thanks for the response though!